# How to call a batch file with parameters from a command prompt

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Below is the line in my power shell script where I call the batch file(with parameters) and I get a positional parameter error.

Could someone please help on how to call a batch file with parameters from a powershell script and how to capture that input parameter from batch file. Thanks

Line in my Power shell script:

> Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c D:\load.bat"  "$Password"

```
--Error:
**PS D:\Oracle\Scripts\Obi> .\XYZ.ps1
Start-Process : **A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'password'.**
At D:\.ps1:4 char:1
+ Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/c D:\load.bat"  "$Password"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand**
```

Script in Batch file (load.bat):

```
set "Var=%1"
for %%i in (*.csv) do (
    sqlldr USERID=userid/%Var%@server:prot/domain, CONTROL=control.ctl, LOG=logfile.log,ERRORS=9999 data='%%i' direct='true'
    move %%i D:\backup
)
```

Comment: Why do you need a batch file? Just run the command you want directly from PowerShell.

Comment: I need the batch because it triggers a sequence of sql procedures and functions. It would be a huge task to convert all in to PS. Is there a way to call the batch from my PS?

Comment: You can just **run the batch file as an executable**

Comment: Also used the below

Comment: Start-Process "D:\load.bat" $PasswordStart                                               
 -Process : Process with an Id of 391020 is not running.
At D:\Oracle\Scripts\Obi\OBIEE_Load_Process.ps1:4 char:1
+ Start-Process "D:\load.bat" $Password
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-Process], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: try this: `cmd.exe /c "D:\load.bat  $Password"`

Comment: "Is there a way to call the batch from my PS?" Yes; just run it (same way you would in cmd.exe).

Comment: Ran this: Start-Process cmd.exe /c "D:\load.bat $Password"                                             same 'PositionalParameter not found' error.

Comment: You don't need `Start-Process`. Just type the batch file's name followed by the parameters you want on the command line. Do exactly like you would do it from a cmd.exe command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a batch file (`cmd.exe` shell script) from a PowerShell prompt, just type the batch file's name, followed by its parameters, and press `Enter`. Remember: PowerShell is a shell, which means it runs command you type, just like `cmd.exe` does. For example:

```
D:\load.bat [param1 [param2 [...]]
```

One difference from `cmd.exe` is that if the command you want to run contains spaces, enclose the command in quotes and invoke it with the `&` (call or invocation) operator. For example:

```
& "D:\Script Tools\load.bat" [param1 [param2 [...]]
```

Just as in `cmd.exe`, if a parameter contains spaces, don't forget to quote it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run:

```
D:\load.bat "$Password"
```

Or:

```
cmd.exe /c D:\load.bat "$Password"
```

However, you should also be able to run:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe' -ArgumentList '/c', 'D:\load.bat', "$Password"
```

Note that `/c` and `'D:\load.bat'` are considered separate arguments.

`Start-Process` can be useful if you want to hide the window (`-WindowStyle Hidden`) or force PowerShell to wait for the script to complete (`-Wait`).  You may need the `-PassThru` parameter if you need a value returned from the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

In doubt, read and follow [`Start-Process` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1).

```
start-process cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c", "D:\load.bat", "$password"
```

Above would run on the assumption that `$password` variable **does not contain** `cmd` poisonous characters (see [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)) like

```
& Ampersand
< Less-Than Sign
> Greater-Than Sign
| Vertical Line
```